# to get data from table without using reference of state

Tags: corda

am trying to get the value from db without using serviceHub and vault.but i couldn't. what my logic is, when i pass the country name, it should return the id's(PK)of that country which is in one table.using those id's, it should return the values related to those id's from other table.it could be possible in flow class.but am trying to do in api class where servicehub couldn't import. Please help me out.

Comment: Is the data stored in the node's database, or in some external database that's separate from the node?

Comment: node's database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the node has access to the `ServiceHub`. The API runs outside of the node in a separate process, so it is limited to interacting with the node via the operations offered by `CordaRPCOps`.

Either you need to store the data you want to access in a separate database outside of the node, or you need to find some way to programatically log into the node's database from the API, using JDBC as described here: https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html.

Comment: how to get all matching data from one state using list of id(PK) from another state ?

Comment: Can you explain the lookup you want to do in more detail? From the example you gave, it didn't sound related to Corda, but more of a general SQL question?